# Running wine in ubuntu docker container

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, wine

I am trying to run windows application in ubuntu which is there in docker container and getting below issue:

Can someone please help me to understand the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the application you tried to run requires a 'Screen', more specifically it requires X to run. X is a windowserver. 
Maybe it's worth looking into this: https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this how to, it may solve your problem:

there’s no X server running inside the container. In order to allow the application running inside the container to access the X server running on the Docker host, we’ll expose the host’s X server UNIX domain socket inside the container. We can ask Docker to bind mount the /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 UNIX socket to the same location inside the container using the --volume parameter:

https://alesnosek.com/blog/2015/07/04/running-wine-within-docker/